# Save product attribute where value contains umlaut

Tags: attributes

I have an issue where I have multiple values in German containing umlauts and other special characters - `Portionsgröße: 30g (ein großer Portionslöffel)`.

```
$var = Portionsgröße: 30g (ein großer Portionslöffel);
```

If I do `$product->setData('attribute_name', $var);` it only saves part of the text. So in this case it would return - `echo $product->getData('attribute_name') - Portionsgr`

htmlspecialchars and htmlentities doesn't fix the issue. Any advice

Comment: is your DB in UTF-8, are your .php scripts in UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the desired result in the end by using the php function `utf8_encode(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine how the variable assignment worked. You should have gotten a syntax error (`syntax error, unexpected ':'`).

Please put single quotes around the value:

`$var = 'Portionsgröße: 30g (ein großer Portionslöffel)';`